# ctex package and indentation

Tags: indentation

It seems that `ctex` package by default indents the first paragraphs. The issue can be solved with `\noindent`, but I would like to restore the default settings for which after a heading no indentation occurs. Here is a MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,english,openright,twoside,a4paper]{book}%
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
I wonder why this paragraph is indented.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The issue occurs both compiling with `pdflatex` and `xelatex`. I found on the web that someone had a similar problem with `xeCJK` and solved it by loading `polyglossia` with some options, but in my document `polygloxia` clashes with other packages.

The question is, if I load `ctex` package how can I avoid the indentation of the first paragraphs?

Comment: Because in Chinese typesetting, the first paragraph is conventionally indented, just like in English typesetting, it is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\usepackage[UTF8,noindent]{ctex}
                 %%%%%%%%
```